# How to implement a more unique name (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have a form to save images with a dynamic number of downloadable images. How can I implement a more unique name for the images with minimal code (MVC)?

```
filenameFile = String.Format(
    "I{0}I{1}P{2}[64x64]{3}",
    instance.Item.Id,
    instance.Id,
    Settings.PropertyPictureId, fileExtension
);
```

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657974/how-to-generate-unique-file-names-in-c

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use a [Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) inside the filename => it will be pretty unique.