# Saving Images to a folder with a numeric system C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, image-processing

I am having some trouble with my program. I'm trying to save images in C# They save but they overwrite themselves when i take new photos on my computer. Is there anyway to automatically name them differently like with numbers? For Example:

- Image1.jpg
- Image2.jpg
- Image3.jpg

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and Coding in C#. This is some of the code im using:

```
  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {   


        Rectangle form = this.Bounds;
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(form.Width, form.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics graphic =
                Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                graphic.CopyFromScreen(form.Location,
                    Point.Empty, form.Size);
            }


                bitmap.Save("C:/Users/G73/Desktop/My OVMK Photos//OpenVMK.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);


        }
    }
```

Comment: *I am using Visual Basics 2012 and Coding in C#*. Whoa dude, mind f*ck.

Comment: If readability doesn't matter use guids: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657974/how-to-generate-unique-file-names-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add something like timestamp:

```
bitmap.Save("C:/Users/G73/Desktop/My OVMK Photos//OpenVMK" + DateTime.Now.ToString(yyyyMMddHHmmss) + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: I don't understand. This is marked as the answer but doesn't solve the requirements of the question. Bad engineering alert. #redflag I'm on my way to meta; This is a great case for community moderated answers in addition to OP selected answers. A case that would break this solution that is solved by the requirements above _and_ correct answers is; what happens if you save two files _in the same second_?

Comment: @Gusdor If this is your problem then use HHmmssffff as the format. If you manage to save it on the same thousandth of a second then ok. My solution gave a way of doing it, but you can still modify it to your needs. As i see it since he is saving it to a user specific folder and it is using a button event which means human intervention  and the fact that he is saving one image at a time, it is highly unlike to do it faster than a second.

Comment: My problem is that it is marked as the answer but it is demonstrably wrong even before the 'within a second' error. 

Consider maintenance scenarios. Code changes could introduce invisible problems very easily. I suppose you could Thread.Sleep for a the lowest increment specified in your string format but not you have 2 things to change if that string format changes (the format, and the sleep). Making the format driven by the increment or visa-verse is more code than the solutions that use the original example format.

Comment: Passing off fail states with 'meh, its rare' is a terrible attitude - one I am guilty in the comments to my own answer. We should strive to fix that mentality.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple implementation could be:

- Count the file with the same name in the folder
- Append Count+1 to the name of the file that you are going to save

Something like:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:/Users/G73/Desktop/My OVMK Photos", "OpenVMK*");
...
var newFileName = string.Format(@"C:/Users/G73/Desktop/My OVMK Photos/OpenVMK{0}.jpg", files.Length+1);
bitmap.Save(newFileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: This will count files that are called "OpenVMKsomethingelse.jpg" which should not count.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
string filename = "file";
string extension = "txt";
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(filename, extension); //desired path

int i = 1;

while(System.IO.File.Exists(path));
{
    //assemble fallback path
    path = System.IO.Path.Combine(string.Format("{0} ({1})", filename, i++), extension);

    if(int == Int32.MaxValue && System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Too many files and commenters are pedants");
}

//save your file
```

Comment: Son, you have bigger problems if you have int.MaxValue files with the same incrementing names in the same pattern. I've edited in a break to the loop but regardless, it will still be an exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Rectangle form = this.Bounds;
    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(form.Width, form.Height))
    {
        using (Graphics graphic =
            Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            graphic.CopyFromScreen(form.Location,
                Point.Empty, form.Size);
        }

        int count = 1;

        string baseFileName = "OpenVMK";
        string ext = ".jpg";
        string pathToFile = "C:/Users/G73/Desktop/My OVMK Photos";            
        while(System.IO.File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(pathToFile, string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", baseFileName, i++, ext))) {};

        bitmap.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(pathToFile, string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", baseFileName, i++, ext)), ImageFormat.Jpeg);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file name **always always** follow patters like

> "image" + number + .jpg

You can code to get maximum number and then create a file name with an incremented

```
string file1 = "image1.jpg";
string file2 = "image13.jpg";
string number = file1.Substring(5, file1.IndexOf(".") - 5);
number = file2.Substring(5, file2.IndexOf(".") - 5);
```

However, it depends on how many files you have. That can impact the performance.
Other option could be:

Write a file which contains only the number (max number)
Whenever you want to write a new image file,

- read that number
- increment it,
- save the image file with incremented number
- and rewrite that file with incremented number

Answer (score 0):

You can just *check existing files* and add 1, 2, 3 etc to the proposed file name:

```
    private static int GetNextFileNumber(String fileFullName) {
      int result = -1;

      String fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileFullName);
      String ext = Path.GetExtension(fileFullName);

      foreach (String file in Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileFullName))) {
        if (!String.Equals(ext, Path.GetExtension(file), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
          continue;

        String name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);

        if (!name.StartsWith(fileName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
          continue;

        if (result < 0)
          if (name.Equals(fileName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            result = 1;

        int num = 0;

        if (int.TryParse(name.Substring(fileName.Length), out num))
          if (num > result)
            result = num + 1;
      }

      return result;
    }

    private static String GetNextFileName(String fileFullName) {
      int number = GetNextFileNumber(fileFullName);

      if (number <= 0)
        return fileFullName;

      return Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileFullName), 
                          Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileFullName) + (number).ToString() + Path.GetExtension(fileFullName));
    }


   ....

   private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   { 
      ....
      // bitmap.Save("C:/Users/G73/Desktop/My OVMK Photos/OpenVMK.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

      // Instead of file_name use GetNextFileName(file_name):
      bitmap.Save(GetNextFileName("C:/Users/G73/Desktop/My OVMK Photos/OpenVMK.jpg"), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
      ....
   }
```