# Add data to the json instead of overwriting it C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

So i have code that writes my data to a JSON with the library newtonsoft. But the problem now is that the JSON gets overwritten everytime instead of addes behind the previeous data.

Here is my code

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);

using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

    writer.WriteStartArray();
    writer.WriteStartObject();
    writer.WritePropertyName("Temperature");
    writer.WriteValue(temperature);
    writer.WritePropertyName("Score");
    writer.WriteValue(score);
    writer.WritePropertyName("TrackId");
    writer.WriteValue(trackId);

    /*
    writer.WriteStartObject();
    writer.WritePropertyName("CPU");
    writer.WriteValue("Intel");
    writer.WritePropertyName("PSU");
    writer.WriteValue("500W");
    writer.WritePropertyName("Drives");
    writer.WriteStartArray();
    writer.WriteValue("DVD read/writer");
    writer.WriteComment("(broken)");
    writer.WriteValue("500 gigabyte hard drive");
    writer.WriteValue("200 gigabyte hard drive");
    writer.WriteEnd();
    */
    writer.WriteEndObject();
    writer.WriteEnd();
}

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:/Users/Kimeru/Documents/Dermalog Noah WPF/data.json", sb.ToString());
```

This is the result I want to achieve:

```
[
  {
    "Temperature": "24.6",
    "Score": "37",
    "TrackId": 3
  }
,
  {
    "Temperature": "16.8",
    "Score": "38",
    "TrackId": 4
  }
]
```

I'm pretty new to the .NET coding world so I'm trying my best to explain.

Comment: It might be simpler to read the existing data into an array of class objects, add to the array, then write out.

Comment: The problem is that it will be big loads of data, so an array will take to much performance in my eyes, or what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `System.IO.File.WriteAllText();` which overrides the existing file.
Simply use `System.IO.File.AppendAllText();` to add your text to the file.

Answer (score 3):

I think a better solution would be to:

1. Read json and convert to list of class object that represents the json objects
2. Add, modify or remove objects from the list
3. Serialize the list of class objects to json
4. Write the new json to the file

I made a little example:

```
public class TrackData
{
    public double Temperature { get; set; }
    public double Score { get; set; }
    public int TrackId { get; set; }
}

    public void WriteJson(string filePath, List<TrackData> trackDataList)
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(trackDataList);

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath))
        {
            sw.Write(json);
        }
    }

    public List<TrackData> ReadJson(string filePath)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            string json = sr.ReadToEnd();

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TrackData>>(json);
        }
    }
```

Now you can use the methods and class this way:

```
        List<TrackData> myTrackDataList = ReadJson("Filepath");


        TrackData newTrackData = new TrackData();
        newTrackData.Score = 38;
        newTrackData.Temperature = 22;
        newTrackData.TrackId = 5;

        myTrackDataList.Add(newTrackData);

        WriteJson("FilePath", myTrackDataList);
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think its good idea to add to a json file like this,
save each object into a new json file so you can read it after.

`Path.GetTempFileName()` should give you a unique file name

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText($@"C:/Users/Kimeru/Documents/Dermalog Noah WPF/{Path.GetTempFileName()}_data.json", sb.ToString());
```

There are other ways to get unique file name generated for you

[How to Generate unique file names in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657974/how-to-generate-unique-file-names-in-c-sharp/4657981)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating object directly create list of objects first and serialize the array and create Json file later Deserialize the array and use Add method to add Json object. This is very easy method try this code.

//create a class
namespace Test1
{

```
class Lad
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }          
    
}


internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        List <Lad> obj = new List <Lad> ();
        
        obj.Add (new Lad { 
                            FirstName = "Markoff",
                            Age = 23,
                        });
        obj.Add(new Lad
        {
            FirstName = "Rahul",
            Age = 32,
        });

        //Serialize Lad object to JSON
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("mydata.json", json);


         var existingData = File.ReadAllText("mydata.json");
        Console.WriteLine(existingData);
        List<Lad> objects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Lad>>(existingData);
       objects.Add(new Lad
                   {
                       FirstName = "Prabhat2",
                        Age = 16,
                    });

       var updatedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objects,Formatting.Indented);
       Console.WriteLine(updatedJson);            
       System.IO.File.WriteAllText("mydata.json", updatedJson);
    }
}
```

}